# Spring Boot Inject Rest Template to Login Filter

Tags: spring, rest, templates, authentication, ldap

in default, my Login Filter output like this :

```
"role": "ROLE_ABC",
"succeed": "Success!",
"id": 123,
"username": "111222333",
"token": "xxxxx"
```

now i want to inject the output of rest tempalte, the output of rest template like this one :

```
    {
  "ResponseHeader": {
    "ErrorCode": "0",
    "ErrorDescription": "Success",
    "TrxId": "123"
  },
  "UserInfo": {
    "UserId": "111222333",
    "FullName": ""
  }
}
```

now i want to inject the output of rest template to my default login filter.

this is my code, im confuse how i can send the Request Body of rest template inside Login Filter

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain,
        final Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.info("successfulAuthentication");
    logger.info(auth);
    Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(auth.getAuthorities());
            String hasil=roles.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "");
            AuthenticationService.addToken(res, auth.getName());

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic uYycjhow9iJOFOJj=");

            HttpEntity<vwCredentials> entity = new HttpEntity<vwCredentials>(product,headers);
            ->variable "product" is request body,
              i confuse where should i put this code "@RequestBody vwCredentials product"

            ResponseEntity<vwJWTLDAP> respon = restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://123/LDAP/", HttpMethod.POST, entity, vwJWTLDAP.class);

            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            String email = auth.getName();
            User user = repository.findByEmail(email);
            map.put("id", user.getId());
            map.put("username", auth.getName());
            map.put("role", hasil);

            //map.put("LDAP", respon); -> I WANT TO CALL LIKE THIS WAY

    map.put("token", AuthenticationService.addToken(auth.getName()));
    map.put("succeed", "Success !");

    String authString = new Gson().toJson(map);


    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.print(authString);
    out.flush(); 

}
```

}

how can i call like this way. //map.put("LDAP", respon); -> I WANT TO CALL LIKE THIS WAY

Answer (score 0):

lass.

You would go about this using the `getBody()` method. This method is inherited from the class [HttpEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#getBody()).

That being said, a way to get it would be `map.put("LDAP", respon.getBody());`

Comment: sure, im adding the getBody()
still got error couse idont sent the product variable in this line

 HttpEntity<vwCredentials> entity = new HttpEntity<vwCredentials>(product,headers);
            ->variable "product" is request body,
              i confuse where should i put this code "@RequestBody vwCredentials product"

Comment: This is part of your controller, should be coming from a client that makes a call to your API. This is received in the body, you can then send it as a parameter to your service. 
For example, It could be something like. 


    `@GetMapping(value="/example")
    public void method(@RequestBody receivedBody){
       someService.someMethod(receivedBody)
    }`

Comment: im sorry, im still lost. do u have any reference? so i can read how to implement that?